# How to set a command with a comand block?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I want to set a testfor commandblock. This is the command I want in the block: `/testforblock 1998 10 657 glass`. What is the setblock command to have this in a commandblock?

Comment: What error does it give

Answer (score 1):

This is the command to setblock with a command block that has a command:

```
/setblock <x> <y> <z> command_block 0 {Command:"/testforblock 1998 10 657 glass"}
```

You just use the command data tag